# How to change color of confusion matrix in pandas_ml

Tags: python, pandas-ml

I'm plotting a confusion matrix using the pandas_ml package in python 2.7 
with the following code

```
cm = ConfusionMatrix(true, pred)
cm.plot( normalized=True)
```

How can I specify a color scheme?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this provided that the backend is not seaborn

```
plt.set_cmap('Blues')
```